# How automatically fill object path to avoid NPE in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have such code:

```
a.b = null
a.b.c = 10 // here is NPE should be thrown
```

Is there way to avoid NPE by some automatic interception and initialization of `b` with new instance value?

In common case the object path may be long like this: `a.b.c.d.e.f = 10`
and any part of path may be met a null value

Comment: What are the types of your fields? Custom classes? Maps?

Comment: The types of fields may be either custom classes or Map<String, CustomClass>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insert safe-navigation operators like `a?.b?.c?.d?.e?.f = 10` you can use a macro to do this "automatically":

```
// I have not tried with assignment so you may need to fill a gap in the macro method
safe(a.b.c.d.e.f = 10)

// I have tested like this:

  @Test
  void testSafeOne() {
    def objExp = null
    def hashCode = safe(objExp.hashCode())
    assert safe(hashCode.toString()) == null
  }

  @Test
  void testSafeMany() {
    def objExp = null
    assert safe(objExp.hashCode().toString()) == null
  }

  @Test
  void testSafeAttr() {
    Integer number = null
    assert safe(number.@MAX_VALUE.abs()) == null
  }

  @Test
  void testSafeAssign() {
    // TODO
  }
```

You need to register this class through the extension mechanism:

```
package macros

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.macro.runtime.Macro
import org.codehaus.groovy.macro.runtime.MacroContext

import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper.*
import static org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GeneralUtils.*
import static org.apache.groovy.ast.tools.ExpressionUtils.isThisExpression

class SafeMacroMethods {
  /**
   * macro version of: <code>objectExpr.?methodName()</code>
   */
  @Macro
  static Expression safe(MacroContext context, MethodCallExpression expression) {
    if (isImplicitThis(context)) {
      expression.tap { safe = true; safe(context, objectExpression) }
    }
  }

  /**
   * macro version of: <code>objectExpr.?propertyName</code>
   */
  @Macro
  static Expression safe(MacroContext context, PropertyExpression expression) {
    if (isImplicitThis(context)) {
      expression.tap {
        if (getClass() == PropertyExpression) {
          it.@safe = true
        } else { // AttributeExpression, etc.
          def field = PropertyExpression.getDeclaredField('safe')
          field.accessible = true
          field.set(it, true)
        }
        safe(context, objectExpression)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * macro version of: <code>targetExpr ?= sourceExpr</code>
   */
  @Macro
  static Expression safe(MacroContext context, BinaryExpression expression) {
    if (isImplicitThis(context)) {
      expression.tap { safe = true; safe(context, leftExpression); safe(context, rightExpression) }
    }
  }

  protected
  static Expression safe(MacroContext context, Expression expression) {
    expression
  }

  private static boolean isImplicitThis(MacroContext context) {
    context.call.with {
      isThisExpression(objectExpression) && isImplicitThis()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi emilles,

Thank you for your advice and good idea to use groovy macros.    

My task is to simplify life of users of my library and to add some ability to avoid extra coding efforts by users to handle null-elements in path.  
User should just to specify path and assignment expression without checking and initialization code like you wrote: safe(a.b.c.d.e.f = 10)  
And macros will create all necessary checking and initialization of path-elements to avoid NPE.    

In any way thank you again for your idea :)

Comment: You can use a local or global transform so that application is automatic.